# Netbeans sFTP Sync - Bidirectional reconciliation

Tags: netbeans, synchronization, sftp, bidirectional

I'm using Netbeans to manage a PHP projects in a proprietary setup. Files are on a web server and I use netbeans sFTP to download and auto-upload the files as I change them. It works great and I've read of others doing this. This takes care of creating/uploading files as I change / create them. It also seems to remove files if I delete them locally.

Now, enter source control (in my case Git, but for this the type shouldn't matter). My source control **has** to be on the web server. This is apart of the proprietary setup.

Lets say I switch branches (which would be done on the web server, to be clear), *can I* and how do I reconcile all the changes from the server? This would include removing files and folders locally that no longer exist in the version I'm working with. It also includes updating file contents for changes.

Now, I **am** aware of the "Download" function in netbeans. In netbeans, I right click on a folder structure or the project (in the "Projects" pane) and Netbeans will proceed to download all changes but it does not *seem* to remove local files and folders that no longer exist on the server..

Answer (score 0):

You may have a look at this [solved issue/enhancement](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=199151). It will be in NetBeans 7.2 and currently it is part of nightly dev builds